# How to count number of occurences of permutation (overlapping) in large text in python3?

Tags: python, arrays, string, algorithm, count

I am having a list of words and I'd like to find out how many time each permutation occurs in this list of word.
And I'd like to count overlapping permutation also. So count() doesn't seem to be appropriate.
for example: the permutation aba appears twice in this string:

ababa

However count() would say one.

So I designed this little script, but I am not too sure that is efficient. The array of word is an external file, I just removed this part to make it simplier.

```
import itertools
import itertools



#Occurence counting function
def occ(string, sub):
    count = start = 0
    while True:
        start = string.find(sub, start) + 1
        if start > 0:
            count+=1
        else:
            return count


#permutation generator
abc="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
permut = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(abc,repeat=2)]


#Transform osd7 in array

arrayofWords=['word1',"word2","word3","word4"]


dict_output['total']=0

#create the array
for perm in permut:
    dict_output[perm]=0

#iterate over the arrayofWords and permutation
for word in arrayofWords:
    for perm in permut:
        dict_output[perm]=dict_output[perm]+occ(word,perm)
        dict_output['total']=dict_output['total']+occ(word,perm)
```

It is working, but it takes looonnnggg time. If I change, product(abc,repeat=2) by product(abc,repeat=3) or product(abc,repeat=4)... It will take a full week!

**The question: Is there a more efficient way?**

Comment: So what is your question now? Doesn't it work?

Comment: No, it is working perfectly. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way to count

Comment: you are looking for substings too, right? How about reversing the logic and just getting all the substrings of `len = 3` let's say and then assigning 0 to everything else? Your dict is going to be incredibly sparse the way you have it

Comment: for example let's take `'ababa'`. The existing substrings of `len = 3` are `['aba', 'bab']` . all others `(26! / (23! * 3!) - 2 = 2598)` are non existant. so you could have a dict like `occ = {'aba':2, 'bab':1}` and everything else would return 0 by `if key not in occ: return 0`

Comment: Do you mean I could hash each words in smaller pieces of length of 3? ex: ababa => aba bab aba?

Comment: @JohnDoetheDoe basically yeah. read the file, get the words, get the substrings of 3, count them and assign 0 to everything else. You seem perfectly competent to code this yourself. Also for working code consider the CodeReview forum. It is exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. To conclude I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768038/string-occurrence-counting-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Very simple: count only what you need to count.

```
from collections import defaultdict

quadrigrams = defaultdict(lambda: 0)    
for word in arrayofWords:
    for i in range(len(word) - 3):
        quadrigrams[word[i:i+4]] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module to count overlapping match.

```
import re
print len(re.findall(r'(?=(aba))','ababa'))
```

Output:

```
2
```

More generally,

```
print len(re.findall(r'(?=(<pattern>))','<input_string>'))
```

Comment: that could replace the `occ` function thus gaining some time, but to see real difference i would propose changing the logic entirely